# Exclamation mark on Wi-FI icon even with good network coverage

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I'm using Sony Xperia Z2, after updated to lollipop 5.1.1 my wifi is not working in spite of a good connection due to that exclamation mark. I read so many related posts and answers here, but i don't understand the technical term/way to solve this problem. I kindly request to explain me in a very simple step-by-step procedure. Thanks

Comment: First of all, the exclamation mark is not what causes your WiFi not to work, it's the other way round; the exclamation mark is there to show that your WiFi is not working.

Comment: What type of wireless network are you trying to connect to (private, home, public, etc.)? Did the Wi-Fi work normally _before_ the update to 5.1.1? How did you perform this update?

Comment: Can you connect to the internet via the same WiFi connection from another device? If you can, does forgetting the WiFi network then connecting again solve the issue?